# How to sort IntPont or LongPoint field in Lucene 6

Tags: lucene

Hi:  I am migrating to Lucene 6 from Lucene 5.1.  I found out that InPoint does not support sorting as its DocValuesType is frozen to NONE and sorting requires NUMERIC.  In Lucene 5.1, I could set the field type of a newmeric field so I could do range based search and sort the result.  I know I can migrate to LegacyIntField but I'd like migrate to the new IntPoint instead.  Does any one know how to index a numeric value to support both range based query and sorting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use additional [SortedNumericDocValuesField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/SortedNumericDocValuesField.html)

```
document.add(new SortedNumericDocValuesField("bid_sorter", bid));
```

and make sort based on it

```
searcher.search(query, hitsPerPage, new Sort(new SortField("bid_sorter", SortField.Type.SCORE, true)))
```

Comment: Honestly NumericDocValues and SortField is enough

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the value in a NumericDocValuesField or its subclasses. 

`doc.add(new NumericDocValuesField(field, 10));`

Then search docs ranked by this field will be :

`Sort sort = new Sort(new SortedNumericSortField(field,
                    SortField.Type.INT, true));
TopDocs topDocs = indexsearcher.search(query, returnedDocNum, sort);`

Comment: you don't have to use SortedNumericSortField, SortField supports doc values